# How to pass the i18n translation object from react-i18next in react-testing-library in conjuction with Redux?

Tags: react-redux, create-react-app, react-testing-library, react-i18next

I have an application that uses Redux and react-i18next for translating the string. I want to write a unit test that will interpolate the i18n object in a human-readable format so that I can test the string as 'Sign in with Google' instead of 'login.sign_in_with_google'. The application was bootstraped with "Create React App". The i18n interpolations work without any problems when the application is actually running. I have to use the `<Suspense />` component, otherwise, it doesn't mount the component.

The project tree:

```
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── locales
│   │   └── en
│   │       └── translation.json
└── src
    ├── i18n
    │   └── i18n.js
```

Component sample:

```js
const Login = (props) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <Button>{t('login.sign_in_with_google')}</Button>
    )
}
```

Test sample:

```js
test('Login with Google button is rendered', async () => {
    // Mount the component
    const { getByText } = render(
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                <Login {...props} />
            </I18nextProvider>
        </Suspense>,
    );

    expect(getByText(i18n.getDataByLanguage('en').login.sign_in_with_google)).toBeDefined();
    await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText(('Sign in with Google'))).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

What I'm getting here is that the component is mounted, but the button string is not interpolated as an i18n object. The bottom line is, **I need to convert i18n keys into human-readable format** so that I can test the component properly.

translation.json file:

```
{
    "login": {
        "sign_in_with_google": "Sign in with Google",
    },
}
```

When I try to log `i18n.getDataByLanguage('en')` it returns undefined.

Comment: Did you try what's suggested here : https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing ?

Comment: I did, the <I18nextProvider> component is from that documentation. I'll try again, maybe I missed something out. When I find the solution, I'm gonna post it here.

Comment: @VladimirJovanović have you found anything?

Comment: @nick Sorry, haven't been writing tests for a long time, but even then (when I asked the question) I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: well no worries man!